# "Pivot step" that Donald Knuth mentioned in TAOCP

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination, sparse-matrices

I stumbled upon the following operation on matrices in section 2.2.6 *Arrays and Orthogonal Lists* in the first volume of *The Art of Computer Programming*, in an example of working with sparse matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
&\vdots&&\vdots&\\
\dots&a&\dots&b&\dots\\
&\vdots&&\vdots&\\
\dots&c&\dots&d&\dots\\
&\vdots&&\vdots&
\end{pmatrix}
\leadsto
\begin{pmatrix}
&\vdots&&\vdots&\\
\dots&1/a&\dots&b/a&\dots\\
&\vdots&&\vdots&\\
\dots&-c/a&\dots&d-bc/a&\dots\\
&\vdots&&\vdots&
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(see it on [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=x9AsAwAAQBAJ&lpg=RA3-PA39&ots=B__YKeO44H&pg=RA3-PA39#v=onepage)).
This operation is called there a "pivot step," the pivot in this case beeing the "$a$" entry in the first matrix.
This operation is stated to be used in algorithms for inverting matrices and solving [systems of] linear equations, and in the simplex method.
It is also cited [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-18317-5_9.pdf) on page 141.

I do not know the simplex method, but I know how to solve systems of linear equations, and usually all operations involved are elementary row transformations.
However, this "pivot step" operation clearly cannot be obtained as a composition of elementary row transformations, neither does it preserve the rank of the matrix (consider the case of a $2\times 2$ matrix with $a = b = c = d$), and I do not understand its "meaning."

What is this operation?

Comment: I read the same section of TAOCP recently, and had the same question… thanks for asking this! While the accepted answer is helpful, I hope to post an answer with more details I learned, but likely I'll never get to it. In the meantime, I found section [5. Systems of Linear Equations](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/numerical-analysis) useful, specifically its pages on Gaussian elimination, LU Decomposition, and Doolittle's Method. Wikipedia [[LU decomposition]] may also be useful. Doolittle's original paper is [here](https://archive.org/details/1878-us-coast-survey-report/page/115/mode/1up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This special "pivot" step consists of a row scaling with $a^{-1}$ and a linear update adding $-c$ times the new top row to the bottom row. This second operation would normally create a zero in the southwest corner. Here this entry is instead used to store the multiplier, i.e., $l_{ij} \gets -c/a$ for future use.

In reality, this pivotal step is part of what is called an in-place LU factorization.  Here the matrix $A$ is overwritten by its factorization $A=LU$, rather than allocate space for new matrices $L = [l_{ij}] $ and $U = [u_{ij}]$.

The factorization is unusual only in the sense that $U$ is scaled by its own diagonal elements, i.e., $u_{ij} \gets u_{ii}^{-1} u_{ij}$ for $i < j$, and the diagonal of $U$ is overwritten with the reciprocal values. The net effect is that subsequent solves involving the same matrix $A$, but new right hand sides $f$, can be carried out with any explicit divisions.

This leads to a minute increase in backward error and an architecture dependent increase in computational speed.

Comment: Row scaling with $a^{-1}$ produces $1$ in the place of $a$.  Is $a^{-1}$ stored there for future use too?

Comment: @Alexey. Indeed. I made a few changes to clarify this point. Thanks.

Comment: I think there could be more clarifications to be made, but essentially this answers my question, thanks.